# Unity List<T> Serialization

Tags: c#, list, serialization, save, loading

Trying to save a List to PlayerPrefs. This is the method I'm TRYING to use...

The List is a a List...

The BaseEnemy class is...

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 [System.Serializable] 
 public class BaseEnemy: MonoBehaviour {


 private StatCalculations statCalculationsScript = new StatCalculations();
 private CalculateXP calculateXPScript = new CalculateXP();

 public bool isAlive;
 public float timeOfDeath;
 public bool isCaptured;
 public int number;
 public string enemyName;
 public string description;
 public bool isFromTrade;
 public int level;
 public int evolveLevel;
 public Types.TypesList type01;
 public Types.TypesList type02;
 public Sexes.SexesList sex;
 public Natures.NaturesList nature;
 public string ability01;
 public string ability02;
 public int baseHP;
 public int baseATK;
 public int baseDEF;
 public int baseSPATK;
 public int baseSPDEF;
 public int baseSPD;
 public int maxHP;
 public int maxATK;
 public int maxDEF;
 public int maxSPATK;
 public int maxSPDEF;
 public int maxSPD;
 public int curHP;
 public int curATK;
 public int curDEF;
 public int curSPATK;
 public int curSPDEF;
 public int curSPD;
 public float evasion;
 public float accuracy;
 public int hpEV;
 public int atkEV;
 public int defEV;
 public int spatkEV;
 public int spdefEV;
 public int spdEV;
 public int hpIV;
 public int atkIV;
 public int defIV;
 public int spatkIV;
 public int spdefIV;
 public int spdIV;
 public int baseEXPYield;
 public LevelingRates.LevelingRatesList levelingRate;
 public int currentXP;
 public int requiredXP;
 public int hpEVYield;
 public int atkEVYield;
 public int defEVYield;
 public int spatkEVYield;
 public int spdefEVYield;
 public int spdEVYield;
 public int baseFriendship;
 public int catchRate;
 public StatusConditions.StatusConditionsList statusCondition;
 public List<BaseMove> enemyMoves = new List<BaseMove>();
 public BaseItem equippedItem;
 public BaseItem EquippedItem{
     get{return equippedItem;}
     set{equippedItem = value;}
 }

 public bool IsCaptured{
     get{return isCaptured;}
     set{isCaptured = value;}
 }
 public string EnemyName{
     get{return enemyName;}
     set{enemyName = value;}
 }
 public string Description{
     get{return description;}
     set{description = value;}
 }
 public bool IsFromTrade{
     get{return isFromTrade;}
     set{isFromTrade = value;}
 }
 public int Number{
     get{return number;}
     set{number = value;}
 }
 public int Level{
     get{return level;}
     set{level = value;}
 }
 public int EvolveLevel{
     get{return evolveLevel;}
     set{evolveLevel = value;}
 }
 public Types.TypesList Type01{
     get{return type01;}
     set{type01 = value;}
 }
 public Types.TypesList Type02{
     get{return type02;}
     set{type02 = value;}
 }
 public Sexes.SexesList Sex{
     get{return sex;}
     set{sex = value;}
 }
 public Natures.NaturesList Nature{
     get{return nature;}
     set{nature = value;}
 }
 public string Ability01{
     get{return ability01;}
     set{ability01 = value;}
 }
 public string Ability02{
     get{return ability02;}
     set{ability02 = value;}
 }
 public int BaseHP{
     get{return baseHP;}
     set{baseHP = value;}
 }
 public int BaseATK{
     get{return baseATK;}
     set{baseATK = value;}
 }
 public int BaseDEF{
     get{return baseDEF;}
     set{baseDEF = value;}
 }
 public int BaseSPATK{
     get{return baseSPATK;}
     set{baseSPATK = value;}
 }
 public int BaseSPDEF{
     get{return baseSPDEF;}
     set{baseSPDEF = value;}
 }
 public int BaseSPD{
     get{return baseSPD;}
     set{baseSPD = value;}
 }
 public int CurHP{
     get{return curHP;}
     set{curHP = value;}
 }
 public int CurATK{
     get{return curATK;}
     set{curATK = value;}
 }
 public int CurDEF{
     get{return curDEF;}
     set{curDEF = value;}
 }
 public int CurSPATK{
     get{return curSPATK;}
     set{curSPATK = value;}
 }
 public int CurSPDEF{
     get{return curSPDEF;}
     set{curSPDEF = value;}
 }
 public int CurSPD{
     get{return curSPD;}
     set{curSPD = value;}
 }
 public int MaxHP{
     get{return maxHP;}
     set{maxHP = value;}
 }
 public int MaxATK{
     get{return maxATK;}
     set{maxATK = value;}
 }
 public int MaxDEF{
     get{return maxDEF;}
     set{maxDEF = value;}
 }
 public int MaxSPATK{
     get{return maxSPATK;}
     set{maxSPATK = value;}
 }
 public int MaxSPDEF{
     get{return maxSPDEF;}
     set{maxSPDEF = value;}
 }
 public int MaxSPD{
     get{return maxSPD;}
     set{maxSPD = value;}
 }
 public float Evasion{
     get{return evasion;}
     set{evasion = value;}
 }
 public float Accuracy{
     get{return accuracy;}
     set{accuracy = value;}
 }
 public int HPEV{
     get{return hpEV;}
     set{hpEV = value;}
 }
 public int ATKEV{
     get{return atkEV;}
     set{atkEV = value;}
 }
 public int DEFEV{
     get{return defEV;}
     set{defEV = value;}
 }
 public int SPATKEV{
     get{return spatkEV;}
     set{spatkEV = value;}
 }
 public int SPDEFEV{
     get{return spdefEV;}
     set{spdefEV = value;}
 }
 public int SPDEV{
     get{return spdEV;}
     set{spdEV = value;}
 }
 public int HPIV{
     get{return hpIV;}
     set{hpIV = value;}
 }
 public int ATKIV{
     get{return atkIV;}
     set{atkIV = value;}
 }
 public int DEFIV{
     get{return defIV;}
     set{defIV = value;}
 }
 public int SPATKIV{
     get{return spatkIV;}
     set{spatkIV = value;}
 }
 public int SPDEFIV{
     get{return spdefIV;}
     set{spdefIV = value;}
 }
 public int SPDIV{
     get{return spdIV;}
     set{spdIV = value;}
 }
 public int BaseEXPYield{
     get{return baseEXPYield;}
     set{baseEXPYield = value;}
 }
 public LevelingRates.LevelingRatesList LevelingRate{
     get{return levelingRate;}
     set{levelingRate = value;}
 }
 public int CurrentXP{
     get{return currentXP;}
     set{currentXP = value;}
 }
 public int RequiredXP{
     get{return requiredXP;}
     set{requiredXP = value;}
 }
 public int HPEVYield{
     get{return hpEVYield;}
     set{hpEVYield = value;}
 }
 public int ATKEVYield{
     get{return atkEVYield;}
     set{atkEVYield = value;}
 }
 public int DEFEVYield{
     get{return defEVYield;}
     set{defEVYield = value;}
 }
 public int SPATKEVYield{
     get{return spatkEVYield;}
     set{spatkEVYield = value;}
 }
 public int SPDEFEVYield{
     get{return spdefEVYield;}
     set{spdefEVYield = value;}
 }
 public int SPDEVYield{
     get{return spdEVYield;}
     set{spdEVYield = value;}
 }
 public int BaseFriendship{
     get{return baseFriendship;}
     set{baseFriendship = value;}
 }
 public int CatchRate{
     get{return catchRate;}
     set{catchRate = value;}
 }
 public StatusConditions.StatusConditionsList StatusCondition{
     get{return statusCondition;}
     set{statusCondition = value;}
 }

 void Awake(){
     isAlive = true;
     SetupEnemy();
 }

 void Start(){
 }

 void Update(){
     SetupGrowingStats();
 }

 public void SetupEnemy(){
     SetupIV();
     ChooseEnemySex();
     ChooseEnemyNature();
     SetupStats();
 }

 private void SetupIV(){
     HPIV = Random.Range(0,15);
     ATKIV = Random.Range(0,15);
     DEFIV = Random.Range(0,15);
     SPATKIV = Random.Range(0,15);
     SPDEFIV = Random.Range(0,15);
     SPDIV = Random.Range(0,15);
 }

 private void ChooseEnemySex(){
     if(ATKIV > 2){
         Sex = Sexes.SexesList.MALE;
     }else if(ATKIV <= 2){
         Sex = Sexes.SexesList.FEMALE;
     }
 }

 private void ChooseEnemyNature(){
     System.Array natures = System.Enum.GetValues (typeof(Natures.NaturesList));
     Nature = (Natures.NaturesList)natures.GetValue (Random.Range(0,24));
 }

 private void SetupStats(){
     MaxHP = statCalculationsScript.CalculateHP (BaseHP, Level, HPIV, HPEV);
     MaxATK = statCalculationsScript.CalculateStat (BaseATK, Level, ATKIV, ATKEV, Nature, StatCalculations.StatTypes.ATTACK);
     MaxDEF = statCalculationsScript.CalculateStat (BaseDEF, Level, DEFIV, DEFEV, Nature, StatCalculations.StatTypes.DEFENSE);
     MaxSPATK = statCalculationsScript.CalculateStat (BaseSPATK, Level, SPATKIV, SPATKEV, Nature, StatCalculations.StatTypes.SPECIALATTACK);
     MaxSPDEF = statCalculationsScript.CalculateStat (BaseSPDEF, Level, SPDEFIV, SPDEFEV, Nature, StatCalculations.StatTypes.SPECIALDEFENSE);
     MaxSPD = statCalculationsScript.CalculateStat (BaseSPD, Level, SPDIV, SPDEV, Nature, StatCalculations.StatTypes.SPEED);
     CurHP = MaxHP;
     CurATK = MaxATK;
     CurDEF = MaxDEF;
     CurSPATK = MaxSPATK;
     CurSPDEF = MaxSPDEF;
     CurSPD = MaxSPD;
     Evasion = 1.0f;
     Accuracy = 1.0f;
     CurrentXP = calculateXPScript.CalculateCurrentXP(Level, LevelingRate);
     RequiredXP = calculateXPScript.CalculateRequiredXP(Level, LevelingRate);
 }

 public void AdjustCurrentHP(int adj){
     CurHP += adj;
     if(CurHP < 0){
         CurHP = 0;
     }
     if(CurHP > MaxHP){
         CurHP = MaxHP;
     }
 }
 public void AdjustCurrentATK(int adj){
     CurATK += adj;
     if(CurATK < 0){
         CurATK = 0;
     }
     if(CurATK > MaxATK){
         CurATK = MaxATK;
     }
 }
 public void AdjustCurrentDEF(int adj){
     CurDEF += adj;
     if(CurDEF < 0){
         CurDEF = 0;
     }
     if(CurDEF > MaxDEF){
         CurDEF = MaxDEF;
     }
 }
 public void AdjustCurrentSPATK(int adj){
     CurSPATK += adj;
     if(CurSPATK < 0){
         CurSPATK = 0;
     }
     if(CurSPATK > MaxSPATK){
         CurSPATK = MaxSPATK;
     }
 }
 public void AdjustCurrentSPDEF(int adj){
     CurSPDEF += adj;
     if(CurSPDEF < 0){
         CurSPDEF = 0;
     }
     if(CurSPDEF > MaxSPDEF){
         CurSPDEF = MaxSPDEF;
     }
 }
 public void AdjustCurrentSPD(int adj){
     CurSPD += adj;
     if(CurSPD < 0){
         CurSPD = 0;
     }
     if(CurSPD > MaxSPD){
         CurSPD = MaxSPD;
     }
 }

 public void AdjustEXP(int adj){
     CurrentXP += adj;
     if(CurrentXP >= RequiredXP){
         Level += 1;
         RequiredXP = calculateXPScript.CalculateRequiredXP(Level, LevelingRate);
         SetupGrowingStats();
     }
 }

 private void SetupGrowingStats(){
     MaxHP = statCalculationsScript.CalculateHP (BaseHP, Level, HPIV, HPEV);
     MaxATK = statCalculationsScript.CalculateStat (BaseATK, Level, ATKIV, ATKEV, Nature, StatCalculations.StatTypes.ATTACK);
     MaxDEF = statCalculationsScript.CalculateStat (BaseDEF, Level, DEFIV, DEFEV, Nature, StatCalculations.StatTypes.DEFENSE);
     MaxSPATK = statCalculationsScript.CalculateStat (BaseSPATK, Level, SPATKIV, SPATKEV, Nature, StatCalculations.StatTypes.SPECIALATTACK);
     MaxSPDEF = statCalculationsScript.CalculateStat (BaseSPDEF, Level, SPDEFIV, SPDEFEV, Nature, StatCalculations.StatTypes.SPECIALDEFENSE);
     MaxSPD = statCalculationsScript.CalculateStat (BaseSPD, Level, SPDIV, SPDEV, Nature, StatCalculations.StatTypes.SPEED);
     CurrentXP = calculateXPScript.CalculateCurrentXP(Level, LevelingRate);
     RequiredXP = calculateXPScript.CalculateRequiredXP(Level, LevelingRate);
 }

 public void SetDead(){
     this.isAlive = false;
     this.timeOfDeath = Time.time;

     ReSpawner.deadEnemy.Add(this);

     this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
 }


}
```

The class that holds the List is EnemyRoster...which is...

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 [System.Serializable]
 public class EnemyRoster : MonoBehaviour {


 public List<BaseEnemy> enemyRoster = new List<BaseEnemy>();

 void Start () {

 }

 void Update () {

 }

}
```

The script I have to handle the saving and loading is this...

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
 using System.IO;

 public class GameMaster : MonoBehaviour {

 public Camera mainCamera;

 private GameObject playerCharacter;
 private GameObject headsUpDisplay;
 private GameObject eventSystem;
 private GameObject pc;
 private GameObject cam;
 private PlayerCharacter pcScript;
 private Vector3 playerSpawnPointPos;

 void Awake(){
     DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
 }

 void Start () {
     playerSpawnPointPos = ChooseSpawnPoint.PickSpawnPoint(Application.loadedLevelName.ToString(), PlayerPrefs.GetString("Last Zone", "Town"));
     playerCharacter = (GameObject)Resources.Load("Prefabs/Player Character Prefab");
     pc = Instantiate(playerCharacter, playerSpawnPointPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
     if(Application.loadedLevelName == "Main Menu" || Application.loadedLevelName == "Character Generation"){
         pc.GetComponent<Movement>().enabled = false;
         pc.GetComponent<BallThrow>().enabled = false;
         pc.GetComponent<Encounter>().enabled = false;
     }
     pc.name = "Player Character";
     pcScript = pc.GetComponent<PlayerCharacter>();
     cam = Instantiate(mainCamera, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
     if(Application.loadedLevelName != "Main Menu" || Application.loadedLevelName != "Character Generation"){
         LoadCharacterData();
         headsUpDisplay = (GameObject)Resources.Load("Prefabs/HUD Prefab");
         eventSystem = (GameObject)Resources.Load("Prefabs/Event System Prefab");
         Instantiate(headsUpDisplay, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
         Instantiate(eventSystem, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
     }
     pcScript.LastZone = Application.loadedLevelName.ToString();
     SaveCharacterData();
 }

 public static string ObjectToStr<BaseEnemy> (BaseEnemy _saveMe)
 {
     BinaryFormatter _bin = new BinaryFormatter ();
     MemoryStream _mem = new MemoryStream ();
     _bin.Serialize (_mem, _saveMe);

     return Convert.ToBase64String (_mem.GetBuffer());
 }
 public static BaseEnemy StrToObject<BaseEnemy> (string _data) where BaseEnemy : class
 {
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (_data)) {
         BinaryFormatter _bin = new BinaryFormatter ();
         try {
             MemoryStream _mem = new MemoryStream (Convert.FromBase64String (_data));

             BaseEnemy _obj = _bin.Deserialize (_mem) as BaseEnemy;

             return _obj;
         } catch (Exception ex) {
             throw new Exception (ex.Message);
         }

     } else {
         throw new Exception ("_data is null or empty");
     }
 }

 public void SaveCharacterData(){
     GameObject pc = GameObject.Find("Player Character");
     PlayerCharacter pcClass = pc.GetComponent<PlayerCharacter>();
     EnemyRoster pcERoster = pc.GetComponent<EnemyRoster>();
     EnemyInventory pcEInventory = pc.GetComponent<EnemyInventory>();

     PlayerPrefs.SetString("Player Name", pcClass.PlayerName);
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Sex", (int)pcClass.PlayerSex);
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Money", pcClass.PlayerMoney);
     PlayerPrefs.SetString("Last Zone", pcClass.LastZone);
     PlayerPrefs.SetString ("EnemyRoster", ObjectToStr<List<BaseEnemy>> (pcERoster.enemyRoster));
     PlayerPrefs.SetString ("EnemyInventory", ObjectToStr<List<BaseEnemy>> (pcEInventory.enemyInventory));
 }

 public void LoadCharacterData(){
     GameObject pc = GameObject.Find("Player Character");
     PlayerCharacter pcClass = pc.GetComponent<PlayerCharacter>();
     EnemyRoster pcERoster = pc.GetComponent<EnemyRoster>();
     EnemyInventory pcEInventory = pc.GetComponent<EnemyInventory>();

     pcClass.PlayerName = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Player Name", "Name Me");
     pcClass.PlayerSex = (Sexes.SexesList)PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Sex", 0);
     pcClass.PlayerMoney = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Money", 0);
     pcClass.LastZone = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Last Zone", "Pallet Town");
     pcERoster.enemyRoster = StrToObject<List<BaseEnemy>> (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("EnemyRoster"));
     pcEInventory.enemyInventory = StrToObject<List<BaseEnemy>> (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("EnemyInventory"));
 }

}
```

The problem is...I'm getting the following error...

> SerializationException: Type UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour in assembly
>   UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null is
>   not marked as serializable.
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers
>   (System.Type type, StreamingContext context) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization/FormatterServices.cs:101)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.CodeGenerator.GenerateMetadataTypeInternal
>   (System.Type type, StreamingContext context) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/CodeGenerator.cs:78)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.CodeGenerator.GenerateMetadataType
>   (System.Type type, StreamingContext context) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/CodeGenerator.cs:64)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.CreateMemberTypeMetadata
>   (System.Type type) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectWriter.cs:442)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.GetObjectData
>   (System.Object obj,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.TypeMetadata& metadata,
>   System.Object& data) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectWriter.cs:430)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteObject
>   (System.IO.BinaryWriter writer, Int64 id, System.Object obj) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectWriter.cs:306)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteObjectInstance
>   (System.IO.BinaryWriter writer, System.Object obj, Boolean
>   isValueObject) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectWriter.cs:293)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteQueuedObjects
>   (System.IO.BinaryWriter writer) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectWriter.cs:271)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteObjectGraph
>   (System.IO.BinaryWriter writer, System.Object obj,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[] headers) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectWriter.cs:256)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize
>   (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Object graph,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[] headers) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/BinaryFormatter.cs:232)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize
>   (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Object graph) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/BinaryFormatter.cs:211)
>   GameMaster.ObjectToStr[List`1] (System.Collections.Generic.List`1
>   _saveMe) (at Assets/Scripts/Game Master/GameMaster.cs:58) GameMaster.SaveCharacterData () (at Assets/Scripts/Game
>   Master/GameMaster.cs:91) CharacterGeneratorGUI.LetsGo () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/GUIs/CharacterGeneratorGUI.cs:128)
>   UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:109)
>   UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[]
>   parameters) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:575)
>   UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters)
>   (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:717)
>   UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:53)
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/UI/Core/Button.cs:35)
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick
>   (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/UI/Core/Button.cs:44)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler
>   handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:52)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler]
>   (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData
>   eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong please? Thanks.

EDIT-So to the BaseEnemy script I added:

```
protected BaseEnemy(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    this.isAlive = info.GetBoolean("isAlive");
    this.Number = info.GetInt32("number");
    this.EnemyName = info.GetString("enemyName");
    this.Description = info.GetString("description");
    this.IsFromTrade = info.GetBoolean("isFromTrade");
    this.Level = info.GetInt32("level");
    this.EvolveLevel = info.GetInt32("evolveLevel");
    //this.Type01 = info.GetEnumerator("type01");
    //this.Type02 = info.GetEnumerator("type02");
    //this.sex = info.GetEnumerator("sex");
    //this.Nature = info.GetEnumerator("nature");
    this.Ability01 = info.GetString("ability01");
    this.Ability02 = info.GetString("ability02");
    this.BaseHP = info.GetInt32("baseHP");
    this.BaseATK = info.GetInt32("baseATK");
    this.BaseDEF = info.GetInt32("baseDEF");
    this.BaseSPATK = info.GetInt32("baseSPATK");
    this.BaseSPDEF = info.GetInt32("baseSPDEF");
    this.BaseSPD = info.GetInt32("baseSPD");
    this.MaxHP = info.GetInt32("maxHP");
    this.MaxATK = info.GetInt32("maxATK");
    this.MaxDEF = info.GetInt32("maxDEF");
    this.MaxSPATK = info.GetInt32("maxSPATK");
    this.MaxSPDEF = info.GetInt32("maxSPDEF");
    this.MaxSPD = info.GetInt32("maxSPD");
    this.CurHP = info.GetInt32("curHP");
    this.CurATK = info.GetInt32("curATK");
    this.CurDEF = info.GetInt32("curDEF");
    this.CurSPATK = info.GetInt32("curSPATK");
    this.CurSPDEF = info.GetInt32("curSPDEF");
    this.CurSPD = info.GetInt32("curSPD");
    this.Evasion = info.GetInt32("evasion");
    this.Accuracy = info.GetInt32("accuracy");
    this.HPEV = info.GetInt32("hpEV");
    this.ATKEV = info.GetInt32("atkEV");
    this.DEFEV = info.GetInt32("defEV");
    this.SPATKEV = info.GetInt32("spatkEV");
    this.SPDEFEV = info.GetInt32("spdefEV");
    this.SPDEV = info.GetInt32("spdEV");
    this.HPIV = info.GetInt32("hpIV");
    this.ATKIV = info.GetInt32("atkIV");
    this.DEFIV = info.GetInt32("defIV");
    this.SPATKIV = info.GetInt32("spatkIV");
    this.SPDEFIV = info.GetInt32("spdefIV");
    this.SPDIV = info.GetInt32("spdIV");
    this.BaseEXPYield = info.GetInt32("baseEXPYield");
    //this.LevelingRate = info.GetEnumerator("levelingRate");
    this.CurrentXP = info.GetInt32("currentXP");
    this.RequiredXP = info.GetInt32("requiredXP");
    this.HPEVYield = info.GetInt32("hpEVYield");
    this.ATKEVYield = info.GetInt32("atkEVYield");
    this.DEFEVYield = info.GetInt32("defEVYield");
    this.SPATKEVYield = info.GetInt32("spatkEVYield");
    this.SPDEFEVYield = info.GetInt32("spdefEVYield");
    this.SPDEVYield = info.GetInt32("spdEVYield");
    this.BaseFriendship = info.GetInt32("baseFriendship");
    this.CatchRate = info.GetInt32("catchRate");
    //this.StatusCondition = info.GetEnumerator("statusCondition");
}

public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    info.AddValue("isAlive", isAlive);
    info.AddValue("number", number);
    info.AddValue("enemyName", enemyName);
    info.AddValue("description", description);
    info.AddValue("isFromTrade", isFromTrade);
    info.AddValue("level", level);
    info.AddValue("evolveLevel", evolveLevel);
    //info.AddValue("type01", type01);
    //info.AddValue("type02", type02);
    //info.AddValue("sex", sex);
    //info.AddValue("nature", nature);
    info.AddValue("ability01", ability01);
    info.AddValue("ability02", ability02);
    info.AddValue("baseHP", baseHP);
    info.AddValue("baseATK", baseATK);
    info.AddValue("baseDEF", baseDEF);
    info.AddValue("baseSPATK", baseSPATK);
    info.AddValue("baseSPDEF", baseSPDEF);
    info.AddValue("baseSPD", baseSPD);
    info.AddValue("maxHP", maxHP);
    info.AddValue("maxATK", maxATK);
    info.AddValue("maxDEF", maxDEF);
    info.AddValue("maxSPATK", maxSPATK);
    info.AddValue("maxSPDEF", maxSPDEF);
    info.AddValue("maxSPD", maxSPD);
    info.AddValue("curHP", curHP);
    info.AddValue("curATK", curATK);
    info.AddValue("curDEF", curDEF);
    info.AddValue("curSPATK", curSPATK);
    info.AddValue("curSPDEF", curSPDEF);
    info.AddValue("curSPD", curSPD);
    info.AddValue("evasion", evasion);
    info.AddValue("accuracy", accuracy);
    info.AddValue("hpEV", hpEV);
    info.AddValue("atkEV", atkEV);
    info.AddValue("defEV", defEV);
    info.AddValue("spatkEV", spatkEV);
    info.AddValue("spdefEV", spdefEV);
    info.AddValue("spdEV", spdEV);
    info.AddValue("hpIV", hpIV);
    info.AddValue("atkIV", atkIV);
    info.AddValue("defIV", defIV);
    info.AddValue("spatkIV", spatkIV);
    info.AddValue("spdefIV", spdefIV);
    info.AddValue("spdIV", spdIV);
    info.AddValue("baseEXPYield", baseEXPYield);
    info.AddValue("levelingRate", levelingRate);
    info.AddValue("currentXP", currentXP);
    info.AddValue("requiredXP", requiredXP);
    info.AddValue("hpEVYield", hpEVYield);
    info.AddValue("atkEVYield", atkEVYield);
    info.AddValue("defEVYield", defEVYield);
    info.AddValue("spatkEVYield", spatkEVYield);
    info.AddValue("spdefEVYield", spdefEVYield);
    info.AddValue("spdEVYield", spdEVYield);
    info.AddValue("baseFriendship", baseFriendship);
    info.AddValue("catchRate", catchRate);
    info.AddValue("statusCondition", statusCondition);
}
```

And in the GameMaster script (handles saving and loading):

```
    private void SaveEnemyRoster(string path, object obj){
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path)){
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<BaseEnemy>));
        xml.Serialize(writer, obj);
    }
}
private List<BaseEnemy> LoadEnemyRoster(string path){
    List<BaseEnemy> tempRoster = new List<BaseEnemy>();
    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path)){
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<BaseEnemy>));
        tempRoster = (List<BaseEnemy>)xml.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    return tempRoster;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes should implement `ISerializable` **and** a serialization constructor, as well as a method `GetObjectData()`. The implementation will look like this;

```
public class BaseEnemy: MonoBehaviour, ISerializable 
{
    //...

    protected BaseEnemey(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        //map all your properties here
        this.isAlive = info.GetBoolean("isAlive");
        //...
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("isAlive", isAlive);
        //...
    }
}
```

Good luck on that one though, you seem to have a *lot* of properties. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182342.aspx) might also help you out.

Off-Topic; out of curiosity, are you creating a Pokemon game?

Comment: Giving Adrian's suggestion a shot first Dion. Although you both said to use ISerializable, the example Adrian linked me to didn't exactly do things the same as what you're suggesting.

And to answer your question, yes I am.

Comment: Sure, that's your call. However, not implementing the serialization constructor will lead to a problem when deserializing. Since you are willing to save *and* load the data, you are going to need it. Good luck anyway!

Comment: Question... when implementing this, for int there's 6 choices and I'm not sure which I should be using.
GetInt16
GetInt32
GetInt64
GetUInt16
GetUInt32
GetUInt64

Comment: For a normal `int`, use `Int32`. To complete your list; `short` equals `Int16`, `int` equals `Int32`, `long` equals `Int64`. Same for the unsigned ones; `ushort` equals `UInt16`, `uint` equals `UInt32` and `ulong` equals `UInt64`.

Comment: Thanks! Now is there a good page you can direct me to in order to broaden my horizon on the difference between short, int and long?

Comment: Of course; look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx) for integral types and [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signedness) for signedness.

Comment: Alright. And one final question. In the "GetObjectData" method example, you referenced the actual variable of the script ("isAlive", isAlive). Is that correct, or am I actually supposed to reference the getter/setter ("isAlive", IsAlive)?

Comment: That won't matter in this case, use the one you prefer :)

Comment: Hmm. Running into a problem.

this.Type01 = info.GetEnumerator("type01");

error CS1501: No overload for method `GetEnumerator' takes `1' arguments

Comment: Make sure the rest works, then you can google to find a way to (de)serialize `Enumerable` and sorts.

Comment: Everything is looking good. Up above I added (to the original post) the changes that have been made. Now I'm just getting the error:

**InvalidOperationException: To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. UnityEngine.Transform does not implement Add(System.Object).**

Comment: Through research it seems this comes from the class inheriting from MonoBehaviour. Apparently anything that inherits from it, cannot be serialized at all. v.v Now to find a workaround.

Comment: An option would be to put all the stats in a seperate class which does not derive from `MonoBehaviour`, and then give `BaseEnemy` a reference to that class.

Comment: Yup! That's exactly what I ended up implementing this morning! Now I just gotta figure out these darn Enumerables. Still researching it. Thanks again for all the help @Dion.

Answer (score 0):

During serialization, the BinarySerializer tries to completely (and automatically) serialize your object but fails because of this: The base class, MonoBehavior, is not serializable.

To achieve what you want, I would suggest implementing the ISerializable interface for your class, this will allow you to have better control over the way you serialize your object.

Here is a simple example of serializing an object by this method: [ISerializable example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/how-to-serialize-an-object-using-an-iserializable-interface/)

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I'll be giving this a shot today to see if it works.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot @Adrian. This really got me on the right path along with Dion's answer.